# Inaccuracy in tracking multiple targets

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am doing some test for tracking multiple target.

I followed the link below to set up multiple target tracking.

https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Detect-and-Track-Multiple-Targets-Simultaneously

I placed two image targets, and placed two boxes (red and blue) to the corners, as shown in Figure 1 and 2. Note that the boxes are placed in the same level.

[image]
[Figure 1]

[image]
[Figure 2]

Then I printed the two image targets and placed them side by side, and played app.

What I expected to see was the two boxes placed side by side in the same level. However, as shown in the Figure 3, red box was placed somewhere higher than the blue box, even though the image targets were placed in the same plane and were touching each other. Note that Figure 3 is a screen capture of the video stream. When I checked the boxes in the game scene, it was confirmed that Vuforia actually placed them in wrong places, putting the red box somewhere higher than the blue box (Figure 4).

Is this inaccuracy an intrinsic limitation of tracking multiple targets? Or, am I doing something wrong?

In advance, thanks for your help.

[image]

[Figure 3 / capture of video stream]

[image]

[Figure 4 / Two boxes positioned in the game scene in play]

Comment: How "good" are the AR targets? Looks to me like they're both fairly low-point-count (would be 1 or 2 stars) which means that the accuracy on them is going to be poor, leading to results like this.

Comment: The ratings of image target were all 5.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure. I only ever did one multi-target project myself, which was to display the same model, but allow the camera to get very close to the image (a tall poster). Didn't have a problem like this as the time.